# htaccess - redirect to https not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Per: https://exp-resso.com/blog/post/2011/08/securing-your-expressionengine-website-with-https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 ^(member|account|checkout|system) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

> This tells your server “If HTTPS is off, and the request starts with
>   member OR account OR checkout OR system (not case sensitive), redirect
>   to `https://current-domain/current-page`”. It’s a nice simple method of
>   locking down entire subfolders / template groups.

I've added this to my htaccess file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond $1 ^(sign-in|sign-up) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
</IfModule>
```

However, when I go to my http://mydomain.com/sign-in, the URL doesn't change to https://mydomain.com/sign-in. Any idea what's wrong?

**EDIT 1:**

My htaccess also has the following (to remove "www") and I wonder if having both might be causing the problem?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT 2:**

Process of elimination, it turns out this is causing the problem:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I comment out the RewriteRule, the https:// is forces. **What's causing the conflict?**

Comment: Any reasons why you use `.htaccess` style files instead of the normal configuration? Those files are error prone, slow everything down and are hard to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put (sign-in|sign-up) condition inside RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(sign-in|sign-up)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie Are you sure, that mod_rewrite is on? Does any redirect work?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I tested it here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it worked.

Comment: When I use this, it works (https everything):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie This redirect must work only for 2 pages: /sign-in and /sign-up. Doesn't it work?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie remove `www` condition for a while for pure testing

Comment: OK - I followed your advice and was able to identify where the problem is. I still don't know how to fix. Please see my latest edit.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie Sorry, needed to sleep. You are asking: "What's causing the conflict?" - it is caused by URL rewrite: /index.php/$1 - the URL becomes /index.php/sign-up from /sign-up. Try to put my HTTPS RewriteRule before index.php RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? (If port == 80 then redirect )

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} member [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} account [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} checkout [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} system
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is `RewriteEngine On` necessary? Do I just copy the `RewriteCond $1 ^(member|account|checkout|system) [NC]` above the `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that rewrite works on your server and that the htaccess is read (e.g. by issuing a redirect on every URL).

Then use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(sign-in|sign-up)` instead of `RewriteCond $1 ^(sign-in|sign-up) [NC]`

It works and is easier to read too

So you htaccess should look like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(sign-in|sign-up) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```